# homebrew nowhere to be found

Tags: command-line, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew using the command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

When I do this I get.

> It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to
>   reinstall you should do the following before running this installer
>   again:
>       rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup

So I run a

```
which brew
```

and I get nothing, just a new line.

I don't want to delete my usr/local.git because there is a lot in my directory. and the

***/usr/local/Cellar*** Doesn't exist and when I cd into ***/usr/local*** there is no brew to be found... Which is due to the simlink I'm sure.

Anytime I run a Brew command of some sort I get

> brew: command not found

I can't figure out what I am missing here. Any clues? I have search for over an hour and can't find any trace of it, even though the install says it does.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is in /usr/local/.git that you don't want to delete? Did you have your own git repo there, or is it the one that belongs to Homebrew?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not exactly sure what it's doing there. After digging deeper into the git repository I can't figure out exactly what it's doing there or how it got there. I suspect it has something to do with yuicompressor.